# error: database is uninitialized and MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD not set

Tags: mysql, docker

ubuntu +docker+ mysql I fail to start it.

> root@i-3c1mg35c:/# docker run -d --volumes-from qiankrbase -p 3307:3307 mysql:latest
>   60474b1b427befe5001a5ecb6f62f40c0a8705064e20fbca18e72975cd994658
>
> root@i-3c1mg35c:/# docker logs 60474b1b427befe5001a5ecb6f62f40c0a8705064e20fbca18e72975cd994658
>   error: database is uninitialized and MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD not set
>     Did you forget to add -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=... ?

How I can initialize my MySQL in docker and use it in my ubuntu server.
I fail to find any answer or tutorial on the web,Plz help me.

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to pass mysql root password as environment variable. You can fix this by creating container this way:

`docker run --volumes-from qiankrbase -p 3307:3307 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -d mysql:latest`

To make your life easier, you can give to container a name with `--name` option, and you can reference by it later on, for example
`docker logs name`

Comment: Anyway,thanks a lot. Now I knoe I can pass the environment value by `-e` and MySQL can get the value from environment.

Answer (score -2):

I got an similar answer in here:http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-manually-build-docker-containers-for-wordpress/

I remove the original container by

`docker remove 60474b1b427befe5001a5ecb6f62f40c0a8705064e20fbca18e72975cd994658`

And then I added the password like this:
```

## docker run -d -v /var/lib/mysql --name qiankrbase -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql123 -p 23:23 -d mysql:latest

`it returns like this:`

2e1d5dcbd2b6a3cf728183a7e51fc29bee467fa77df3c4bf165772635d241d0f

`init mysql by docker logs`

docker logs 2e1d5dcbd2b6a3cf728183a7e51fc29bee467fa77df3c4bf165772635d241d0f

`It return lots of craps..`

Running mysql_install_db ...
2015-05-28 08:40:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.24) starting as process 17 ...
2015-05-28 08:40:01 17 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-05-28 08:40:01 17 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-05-28 08:40:01 17 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-05-28 08:40:01 17 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-05-28 08:40:

`chech mysql:`

## service mysql status

`It return:`

 * MySQL Community Server 5.6.24 is running
```

success!